# Action form forward path not a url

Tags: servlets, model-view-controller, struts-1, actionform

What does it mean when I have a path like the example below in the first forward (then success forward)

```
<action
            type="com.testpackage.servlettest"
            path="/ClassHomepage"
            scope="request">
            <forward
                name="success"
                path=".class.homepage"
                redirect="true" />
            <forward
                name="failure"
                path="/Homepage.do"
                module="/"
                redirect="false" />
        </action>
```

I understand the failure forward will forward to the page "/Homepage.do" if "failure" is returned

```
return mapping.findForward("failure");
```

But what happens if I return

```
return mapping.findForward("success");
```

What package will this try to load? How do I find out by looking at `web.xml` and `struct-config.xml` files?

Comment: I guess you are using `tiles`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using tiles, and you need to look in your tiles definition file (usually something like `WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml`). Search for a `<definition name=".class.homepage"> ... </definition>` to find out which view it will direct to.